# Use Automator to copy single folder to multiple locations

Tags: macos, finder, automator

I have several website project folders in a structure like this:

```
Client Work

|- Client 1
  |- client1site
    |- admin
      |- core

|- Client 2
  |- client2site
    |- admin
      |- core

|- Client 3
  |- client3site
    |- admin
      |- core
```

The diagram above just shows the key folders, there are others. There are also more than 3 clients, but the structure is the same for all.

The core folder is part of a CMS, and is identical on all sites. This is updated regularly.

I would like to be able to use Automator to copy a single instance of this core folder, stored somewhere else on my computer (can be anywhere), and replace all of the instances of /admin/core in my Client Work folder.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've updated my answer, you do not necessarily need to create a _variable_ for each _target_. I had forgotten to check the [✓] Replace existing files _check box_ on one and it didn't complete properly and though I need to use a _variable_ instead, which in this use case it wasn't necessary. Sorry for any confusion. That said, using a _variable_ for each does help in knowing which Client is the _target_ where as just selecting the target folded they all look the same.

Comment: Just a thought. Wouldn't it be simpler and easier to use aliases or something in each client folder to point to an external copy of the admin/core folder, since you seem to want it to be identical across clients?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done in **Automator**.

Create a new **Workflow** and add a **Get Specified Finder Items** *action* adding the **core** *template folder* to it.

Add a **Copy Finder Items** *action*, one for each of the *Client* sites.

For each **Copy Finder Items** *action*, do the following

- Check the **[✓] Replace existing files** *check box*.
- In the **To:** *list box*, select: **Other…**

  - In the **Choose** *dialog box*:

    - Navigate to the **admin** *folder* of the appropriate *Client (number)*.
    - Click the **Choose** *button*.

Having done this for each *Client* the *workflow* will then *copy* the **core** *template folder* to the **admin** *folder* of each *Client folder*, thus replacing it and it now having the contents of the updated **core** *template folder* in each of the *Client folders* at the designated location.

---

If you want to be able to know, more easily, which Client the **Copy Finder Items** *action* is for, do the following instead:

- Check the **[✓] Replace existing files** *check box*.

  - In the **To:** *list box*, select: **New variable…**
  - In the **Variable Options** *dialog box*:

    - Change the *text* for **Name:** to an appropriate designator, e.g.: PathToClient1
    - In the **Path** *list box* choose **Other…**, then navigate to the **admin** *folder* of the appropriate *Client (number)*.
    - Then click the **Choose** *button*.

By creating a *variable name* for each *Client folder* there is no ambiguity which **Copy Finder Items** *action* is for which *Client folder*. Although this does assume you select the proper target folder for each. ;)

---

Folder structure before **Automator** *workflow*:

[image: Folder structure before Automator workflow]

**Automator** *workflow*:

[image: Automator workflow]

Folder structure after **Automator** *workflow*:

[image: Folder structure after Automator workflow]

Folder structure after updating the **core** *template folder* and running the **Automator** *workflow* again:

[image: Folder structure after Automator workflow]